# Android: Can we show hiragana text above kanji?

Tags: android

I am working with Japanese on Android device. There is an idea that I want to show a hiragana text above the kanji to increase user experience. However, after a few days research I am still not able to find out the solution for doing that.

The questions are:

1/ Is there anyway to do it (framework or third party)?

2/ Is there any applications which can do the same thing? I will contact the developers for more information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why was this question closed? Hiragana over kanjis is called furigana and is a very common way to show how a difficult kanji is pronounced. You even see this in subtitles of Japanese movies, text books, etc.

Comment: It can be fairly easily done by implementing a custom subclass of ReplacementSpan. This works way better than the FuriganaView in the answer. I could provide the source if this question was re-opened.

Comment: @digorydoo: Thank you for your kindness. The question is closed by other guys, I am not able to re-open it. Sad 

Comment: Have you tried in HTML? `<ruby>食<rt>た</rt></ruby>べる`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one on github, hope it may help for everyone who hava the same problem as me: [FuriganaView](https://github.com/sh0/furigana-view)